# Terragrunt - use dependancy in root provider block

Tags: azure, terraform, terragrunt

I want to use logic in the root file generate block that will inject the Azure sub ID based on file path including the word 'subscription' or not.

This will create a provider using a pipeline variable that creates the sub providers.tf, and then use that sub's ID in all subsequent module's providers.tf.

I can't think how I would inject the sub's ID into the subsequent providers.

I already have a dependancy saying create the sub first.

```
locals {

  module_name = basename(get_terragrunt_dir())

  subscription_id = get_env("SUBSCRIPTION_ID")

}

 

generate "provider" {

  path      = "providers.tf"

  if_exists = "overwrite"

  contents = <<EOF

terraform {

  required_version = "= 1.5.0"

  required_providers {

    azurerm = {

      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"

      version = "= 3.66.0"

    }

  }

}

  %{ if local.module_name == "subscription" }

provider "azurerm" {

  features {}

  subscription_id = "${local.subscription_id}"

}

  %{ endif }

 

  %{ if local.module_name != "subscription" }

provider "azurerm" {

  features {}

  subscription_id = "WHAT DO I NEED HERE TO CALL THE SUB ID I CREATED"

}

  %{ endif }

EOF

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a dependancy listed in my vnet.hcl config file

```
dependency "sub" {
  config_path = "../sub"
}
```

And surprisingly, terragrunt is letting me call it in the root terragrunt.hcl file:

```
  %{ if local.module_name != "subscription" }

provider "azurerm" {

  features {}

  subscription_id = "${dependency.sub.outputs.subscription_id}"

}

  %{ endif }
```